# If f is a characteristic polynomial of $A$, then $f(A)=0$.

Tags: finite-fields, characteristic-polynomial

As we know, The characteristic polynomial $f$ of a
binary matrix $A\in M_m(F_2)$ is defined as $f(x) = |xI + A| \in F_2[x]$. And I saw a lemma from a cryptography paper that If $f$ is a characteristic polynomial of $A \in M_m(F_2)$, then $f(A) = 0$. But $x$ is a vector and A is a matrix. Why there is $f(A)$?

Comment: This is the Cayley-Hamilton theorem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cayley%E2%80%93Hamilton_theorem

Comment: 1) The result you mention is known under the name "Cayley-Hamilton theorem" 2) Usually, the characteristic polynomial of $A$ is $\det(A-xI)$ with a minus sign.

Comment: thx. I'll check out the wiki.

Comment: Yes, you can substitute a matrix into a polynomial. If you have a polynomial $f(x)=a_0+a_1x+a_2x^2+\ldots+a_nx^n$ (where $x$ is a *variable*), and $A$ is a matrix, then $f(A):=a_0I+a_1A+a_2A^2+\ldots+ a_nA^n$.